# Shortest way to check for null and assign another value if not

Tags: c#, .net, null, variable-assignment

I am pulling `varchar` values out of a DB and want to set the `string` I am assigning them to as "" if they are `null`. I'm currently doing it like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(planRec.approved_by) == true)
  this.approved_by = "";
else
  this.approved_by = planRec.approved_by.toString();
```

There seems like there should be a way to do this in a single line something like:

```
this.approved_by = "" || planRec.approved_by.toString();
```

However I can't find an optimal way to do this.  Is there a better way or is what I have the best way to do it?

Comment: The == true is superfluous here...

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.approved_by = IsNullOrEmpty(planRec.approved_by) ? string.Empty : planRec.approved_by.toString();
```

You can also use the null-coalescing operator as other have said - since no one has given an example that works with your code here is one:

```
this.approved_by = planRec.approved_by ?? planRec.approved_by.toString();
```

But this example only works since a possible value for `this.approved_by` is the same as one of the potential values that you wish to set it to.  For all other cases you will need to use the conditional operator as I showed in my first example.

Comment: Doesn't this null coalescing operator throw a nullreference anyways? The way I see this code does the following: `if (planRec.approved_by == null) { this.approved_by = planRec.approved_by.toString(); //<= nullref } else { this.approved_by = planRec.approved_by;}`. If I'm wrong please point out the error.

Comment: @Destrictor is right, the code is broken.  Here's a fix using another fun operator: `this.approved_by = planRec.approved_by?.toString() ?? "";`   <- That's the null-conditional operator, and I don't think it was around when this question was first asked and answered.  Hopefully OP sees this, so he can go refactor his 7 year old code, from two jobs ago :) .

Comment: I could swear I've seen some kind of syntax that lets you assign to an attribute of an object if that object isn't null, like someObject?.someAttribute = value; but I can't seem to find anything like that.

Answer (score 87):

Starting with C# 8.0, you can use the `??=` operator to replace the code of the form

```
if (variable is null)
{
    variable = expression;
}
```

with the following code:

```
variable ??= expression;
```

More information is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: Is there a VB.net version of this?

Comment: Be awesome if you could extend this with conditional access as well eg
variable1.variable2?.variable3 ??= value;

Comment: This is not exactly as the author asked - more specifically this answers to subject question, but not the question body (author intention). But this is the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 64):

You are looking for the C# coalesce operator: ??.  This operator takes a left and right argument.  If the left hand side of the operator is null or a nullable with no value it will return the right argument.  Otherwise it will return the left.

```
var x = somePossiblyNullValue ?? valueIfNull;
```

Comment: This answer does not cover the all cases from the question (only partially). Notice, that there is "string.IsNullOrEmpty". So Empty case is not handled here.

Comment: upvoted because this was the answer I was looking for. (I just needed the null check)

Answer (score 42):

The [coalesce operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is what you want, I believe.

Comment: Yep...but only because the default is "".

Comment: Um, how so? One can use any expression to replace null with..

Answer (score 30):

My guess is the best you can come up with is

```
this.approved_by = IsNullOrEmpty(planRec.approved_by) ? string.Empty
                                                      : planRec.approved_by.ToString();
```

Of course since you're hinting at the fact that `approved_by` is an `object` (which cannot equal ""), this would be rewritten as

```
this.approved_by = (planRec.approved_by ?? string.Empty).ToString();
```

Answer (score 26):

With C#6 there is a slightly shorter way for the case where planRec.approved_by is not a string:

```
this.approved_by = planRec.approved_by?.ToString() ?? "";
```

Answer (score 25):

Use the C# coalesce operator: ??

```
// if Value is not null, newValue = Value else if Value is null newValue is YournullValue
var newValue = Value ?? YourNullReplacement;
```

Answer (score 14):

To extend [@Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120557/c-shortest-way-to-check-for-null-and-assign-another-value-if-not/1120569#1120569)...if planRec.approved_by is already a string

```
this.approved_by = planRec.approved_by ?? "";
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is the 8th most voted :/

Comment: Finally a correct answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

To assign a non-empty variable without repeating the actual variable name (and without assigning anything if variable is null!), you can use a little helper method with a `Action` parameter:

```
public static void CallIfNonEmpty(string value, Action<string> action)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        action(value);
}
```

And then just use it:

```
CallIfNonEmpty(this.approved_by, (s) => planRec.approved_by = s);
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer was correct in time, when it was given.

For people still finding this question:
Today you can use the ??= Operator.

e.g:

```
private string _test = null;

private void InitIfNull(){
 _test ??= "Init";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in your query, for instance in sql server, google `ISNULL` and `CASE` built-in functions.

Answer (score -4):

I use extention method SelfChk

```
static class MyExt {
//Self Check 
 public static void SC(this string you,ref string me)
    {
        me = me ?? you;
    }
}
```

Then use like

```
string a = null;
"A".SC(ref a);
```

Comment: I guess you mean but not easy to read and understand, is that so?

Comment: Ups! You are absolutely right: Very short, but NOT easy to read and understand (at least if you are not used to this notation)