# How do I check an object property for Null before using it for assignment in C# 8?

Tags: c#

I want to check an objects for null be for using it in assignment statement in C#.

**Consider the following C# class definitions:**

```
class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public Bar FooBar { get; set; }
}
class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}
```

**Consider the following code snippet:**

```
var foo1 = new Foo()
{
    FooId = 1,
    FooBar = new Bar()
    {
        BarId = 2
    }
};

var foo2 = new Foo()
{
    FooId = 1,
};

foo1.FooBar.BarId = foo2.FooBar == null ? foo2.FooBar.Barid : 0;
```

The following works fine, but seems a little outdated.

**foo1.FooBar.BarId = foo2.FooBar == null ? foo2.FooBar.Barid : 0;**

In C# 8 is there a different/better way to write the following using null coalescing?

Comment: I don't know why anyone would write code like `foo2.FooBar == null ? foo2.FooBar.Barid : 0`. Best-case, you'll always get `0`. Looks like the opposite of what you actually want.

Comment: Assuming what you really meant was `foo2.FooBar != null ? foo2.FooBar.Barid : 0`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249006) in the duplicate. I.e. `foo1.FooBar.BarId = foo2.FooBar?.BarId ?? 0;`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use null coalescing.

```
int X = obj1?.prop1 ?? 0;
```

Unless I misunderstood the question. You can even chain these if you need, or use a nullable field and set the value later to 0 in a getter.

This even accounts for the original object possibly being null (as the ?. operator will return null too).

Comment: This will throw if `obj` is null

Comment: You can use a conditional access operator.

Comment: obj1?.prop2 ?? 0;

Comment: Obviously I know that =)

Comment: I didn't get that from your info you provided.

Comment: Please read the question and change your answer to solve OP's problem.

Comment: What kind of way of accessing it are you looking for? The conditional access and null coalesce is how I access c# properties for objects that can be null.